# Rename MFC CArchive Serialized class

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using MFC's CArhive class to save off a project file for my app. One of the class names is wildly inaccurate and I'd like to change it, but simply changing the name everywhere renders previous archive files useless with an archive error. Is there a way to change the name of the archived class without rendering all previously saved files useless?

That is of course without using a typedef to access the existing class with a new name or keeping around a version of the class with the old name to read archived files and copying the read in objects to the same class with a new name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crucial point is that when you use `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL`, a `CRuntimeClass` member is added to your class containing the name in its `m_lpszClassName` field.
This `CRuntimeClass` object is also added to a list maintained by the framework that is searched when classes are dynamically created.
You need to make sure that the `CRuntimeClass` object contains the old name of your class in `m_lpszClassName`.

The two options you have are:

1. Override the construction of the
   `CRuntimeClass` object to set the name
2. Change the class name stored in its
       `m_lpszClassName` field after it has
       been created

### Overriding the construction of the CRuntimeClass object

To do this, you will need to make your own versions of `DECLARE_DYMAMIC`, `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`, `DECLARE_SERIAL`, `IMPLEMENT_DYMAMIC`, `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE`, and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL`.
You can just copy and rename the existing implementations.
In your version of `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC`, you need to change the code that constructs the `CRuntimeClass` so that it is initialised with the old class's name.

### Changing the class name stored in the m_lpszClassName field after the CRuntimeClass object has been created

As the `CRuntimeClass` is created by a static initializer, I don't think that you can do this from within your class.
I think that the best place to do it is in your application's `InitInstance`.
Add a `static char*` variable to your application's class containing the old class name.
Then, in `InitInstance`, set the `m_lpszClassName` field in your class's `CRuntimeClass`.

- The first method has the advantage of
  keeping changes within the class
  itself.
- The second makes the application
  aware of the class in a way that it
  possibly shouldn't be.

Either way, the first thing to do is to completely familiarise yourself with the way dynamic creation and serialization work.

Comment: Probably quicker to write a utility to transform the contents of the saved files so they use the new name... +1 for a thorough answer that makes it clear what's involved.

Comment: @Kate Gregory, thanks, I'd go with converting the files as well, perhaps in an override of OpenDocumentFile rather than a separate program though, as this would be transparent to customers if the document files are theirs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I decided to just go ahead and leave the class name alone. Doesn't seem like it's worth that much effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd option which I took. I originally named one of my serializable classes `CEvent` which didn't seem to be a problem on VC6.0; but on VS2010 there is a MFC built-in class called `CEvent` so I had to change it.

So, I fixed it by modifying old format files before calling `COleServerDoc::OnOpenDocument`

I simply, open, read to memory, find and replace `CEvent` with any other 6 character (has to be same size) class name, write and save as new filename, then open and read new file, no problem.

I'm changing file extension for the new version anyway, so it all works out.

Comment: Thanks for another option. I've never looked at the archive file in a text editor, but don't you run up against any potential issues with metadata or your strings that have been serialized being changed by doing such an operation?